# Catching error with Usermanager.getUser() in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-api, google-apps-script

I am working withing Google Spreadsheet creating a script file that has to deal with obtaining user information on my Google Apps Domain. I have admin rights and the Provisioning API is enabled. In my code, I am trying to catch the error when looking up a specific user on a Google Apps Domain (user not found) and instead display a message and continuing on with the rest of the program. The try-catch statement I have here works when there is no error on the user. However, when there is an error on retrieving the user, I get the error: "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation". Here is my code:

```
function testOfDomainAccess() {

var i=0;
var anArray= ["johhn.smith", "susan.que]; //john smith misspelled
var user;

for (i=0; i < anArray.length; ++i)
{ 
Logger.log("\nThe current user being processed is " + anArray[i]);

try 
{
user = UserManager.getUser (anArray [i]);
}
catch (error)
{
  Browser.msgBox("Error: " + error.name + "\n Check your spreadsheet for misspellings of " + anArray[i] + " and We will continue to the next user.");
  user = null;
}

if (user != null) {
//Perform tasks 
}

else
  Logger.log("User not found in domain. Moving on the next item in the array.");
}
```

If anyone can help with this problem I would greatly appreciate it. I am new to Google Apps Script and Provisioning API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the same bug reported at http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=980.

The workaround is to replace the Browser.msgBox() call with Logger.log() and your script should run as expected.